# Estimates for the absolute value of the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1(2-n,n+2,2;x)$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: hypergeometric-functions

I would like to know whether the estimate
$$
|{}_2F_1(2-n,n+2,2;x)| \le \frac{n}{2}, \quad x \in [0,1]
$$
holds and in that case where to find a reference.

Comment: It certainly doesn't hold when $n=0$.

Comment: It seems false for $n < 2$, equality for $n=2$, true for $n>2$ ?

Comment: But false for $n$ not an integer... limit at $x=1$ is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $n$ is meant to be an integer $\geq 2$. Then your function is essentially a Jacobi polynomial with parameters $\alpha=1$, $\beta=2$ and you ask for the maximum absolute value on the interval of orthogonality. You can use Theorem 7.32.1 in Szegö, Orthogonal polynomials, which more generally gives the maximum explicitly for $\alpha,\,\beta\geq -1/2$. In your case it is assumed at the endpoint $x=1$ and is indeed equal to $n/2$.

Comment: Thank you very much !!  It has been extremely useful and the reference to Szego determinant. Good job!